# Error in insert data into table

Tags: php

I have follow an instruction on how to create a shopping cart, I want to make a modification so the shopping cart system can be use as a restaurant system for staff to record customer order, so the system do not need to record the customer details. I have error when I try to insert all the chosen data into table, the error happens in cart.php.

Here is the error:

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\emakengku\cart.phpon line 7

Notice: Undefined index: quantity inC:\xampp\htdocs\emakengku\cart.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: price in C:\xampp\htdocs\emakengku\cart.phpon line 9

Here is the code for index.php

```
<?
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require("connection.php");
if(isset($_GET['page'])){

    $pages=array("products", "cart");
    if(in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)) {

        $_page=$_GET['page'];

    }else{

        $_page="products";

    }

}else{

$_page="products";

}
?>



<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<body>
</body>
</html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

});
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="main">
<?php require($_page.".php");     ?>

</div>

<div id="sidebar">
<h1>Cart</h1>

<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){

$sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_product IN (";

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
$sql.=$id.",";
}
$sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

?>
<p><?php echo $row['name'] ?> x <?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity'] ?></p>
<?php }

?>

<hr />
<a href="index2.php?page=cart">Go to Cart</a>


<?php





}else{

echo "<p>Your Cart is empty</p>";

}
?>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Products.php

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="add"){

        $id=intval($_GET['id']);

        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){

            $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;

        }else{

            $sql_s="SELECT * FROM products
                WHERE id_product={$id}";
            $query_s=mysql_query($sql_s);
            if(mysql_num_rows($query_s)!=0){
                $row_s=mysql_fetch_array($query_s);



                    $_SESSION['cart'][$row_s['id_product']]=array(
                            "quantity" => 1,
                            "price" => $row_s['price']

                            );


                }else{

                    $message="This product id it's invalid!";


        }
        }
        }




?>


<h1>Product List</h1>
<?php 

    if(isset($message)){
    echo "<h2>$message</h2>";
    }
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY name ASC";

$query=mysql_query($sql);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
    <td>RM <?php echo $row['price'] ?></td>
    <td><a href="index2.php?page=products&action=add&id=<?php echo $row['id_product'] ?>">Add To Cart</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>

</table>
```

cart.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require("connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit2']))

    $name=$_POST["name"];
    $quantity=$_POST["quantity"];
    $price=$_POST["price"];
 $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO order ('name', 'quantity', 'price') 
values ('name', 'quantity', 'price')";
echo "sucess!";



 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val) {
    if($val==0) {
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
    }else{
    $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity']=$val;



    }
    }


 }

?>



<a href="index2.php?page=products">Go back to product page</a>
<h1>View Cart</h1>

<form method="post" action"index2.php?page=cart">

<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Item Price</th>



</tr>
<?php

    $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_product IN (";

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
$sql.=$id.",";
}
$sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
$totalprice=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $subtotal=$_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity']*$row['price'];
    $totalprice+=$subtotal;

?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['id_product'] ?>]" size="5" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity'] ?>"</td>
<td>RM <?php echo $row['price'] ?></td>
<td>RM <?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity']*$row['price'] ?></td>



</tr>



<?php 
}

?>
<tr>
<td>Total Price: <?php echo $totalprice  ?></td>


</tr>

</table>
<button type="submit" name="submit"> Update Cart</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit2"> Update Cart</button>


</form>
<br />
<p> To remove an item,set the quantity to 0</p>
```

Comment: link is broken.  maybe post that code here:  http://pastebin.com/ Also post the code here on your question

Comment: i have edit.i dont know how to post the code here. it says i have wrong format.sorry sir

Comment: You also should tell us what error you get and what other code you have involved in this operation.  To put code in a question, copy + paste the raw source into the input, highlight it and press Ctrl+K.  If you aren't sure before submitting you can see a live preview below it.

Comment: thanks sir,i have edit the post.u can check it now.

Comment: wrap your `if(isset($_POST['submit2']))` inside `{ ... }` like you did on the `if` statement below it for `submit`

Comment: also might want to remove `<body></body></html>` from under the `Untitled Document` code in your index.php

Comment: `<form method="post" action"index2.php?page=cart">` you left off the `=` after action

Comment: Please Learn the basics of PHP, your questions are common mistakes of those who do not know the language well. Your problem is not with the code but with lack of knowledge.

Comment: yeah,i admit it.my lecturer just teach me echo hello world and she ask me to create whole system with the lesson of echo hello world.

Comment: @Deryck can u explain me about the "<form method="post" action"index2.php?page=cart"> you left off the = after action" ? sorry,i follow this tutorial from youtube.

Comment: its echo the sucess,but when i check in my table,there is no data inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Change the sql query like this and try. ie remove the single quotes for the column names.

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO order (name, quantity, price) 
    values ('name', 'quantity', 'price')";
```

And make sure that the following values is there. ie, You might have specified the cart.php as the action page of any html form page and the form should use the method "POST".

```
$name=$_POST["name"];
$quantity=$_POST["quantity"];
$price=$_POST["price"];
```

Comment: its echo the sucess,but when i check in my table,there is no data inserted